# Is using the same item in mobile legends even worth it?

Tags: mobile-legends

I've played karina in a classic game, then it took about more than 20 minutes to finish the game. During that period, I had decided to change my holy crystal and ligthning truncheon with bloodwings which grants you 150 of magic power. Including the already bought bloodwings, I had 3 of them altogether but didn't show any powerful effects as I thought.

Answer (score 5):

The items's effects can be separated into stat boosts and unique passives.  2 
of the same Unique passive will not stack, as stated in game. Stat boosts will stack.

I typically focus on the different unique passives. I would recommend looking at the gear loadouts the game suggests, and then be able to prioritize which one would be most useful during a game.

Buying the same item can be useful.  For example, on mages I buy the basic mp regen item twice, as the increased regen means I rarely run out of mana, even while using my skills often.  However, I think this is less true in the mid-game, you will want to be moving towards items with unique passives.

Answer (score 0):

Well, but for some fighters . Blade of despair they would buy double , just for the huge damage. Although i still recommend you to buy each item once as it is far more worth